# How do I transfer a value between webpages using local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SwinTech</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="apply.html" method="post">
        <div class="consultantinformation">
            <h2> Job reference number: </h2>
            <br>
            <h4 id="jobreference2"> 6LZ9W </h4>
        </div>
        <button id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", setItem);
        localStorage.setItem("jobreference1", "1FN43");
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to transfer "jobreference1" from the 1st snippet to the 2nd using local storage. As you can see, I've stored it in one external JavaScript file and sent it to another. But when I try to call it in the HTML code in the 2nd snippet, to which the value was transferred to, it simply doesn't work. I've decided to include all of my HTML and JavaScript code for my second snippet because I believe that's where the issue lies. Thank you.

Note: no Inline JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: You have on local storage per origin. You can share data between origins with a storage

Comment: @jabaa Would you mind elaborating? I don't really understand. Thank you.

Comment: Can you only do that with session storage?

Comment: Your question unclear. If it works with session storage, it also works with local storage.

Comment: @jabaa Maybe I worded it wrong but by webpages I meant pages on the same website. So when you submit the form on the first website, it stores that value and retrieves it on the form you are redirected to. That is shown in the snippets I sent.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? Currently there is much unrelated code and multiple unnecessary files involved.

Comment: @jabaa Done. But I believe the entire JavaScript code is needed to solve this. If this isn't enough to determine that, I'll keep the HTML code the same length but include the entire JavaScript code, as I have reason to believe that's the source of the problem.

Comment: How do you send the forms? There is no button. Please read [mcve]. The code should be minimal but reproducible. When do you execute this line `localStorage.setItem("jobreference1", "1FN43");`?

Comment: Is it possible that your JavaScript code is evaluated before the DOM is loaded? Could you move the script tags to the bottom of the body?

Comment: @jabaa I apologise. I thought I'd added it in but made a mistake when cutting the code. I thought that piece of code executes when you submit the form? What else do I need to add to it?

Comment: @jabaa I can't use inline JS.

Comment: You already have `<script src="..."></script>` in your HTML code. Move it to the bottom of the body. _"I thought that piece of code executes when you submit the form?"_ No, it doesn't. Why would it? Please provide a [mcve]. That doesn't mean minimal code snippets. That's a minimal but complete code that reproduces the problem. That's not your whole project. If your HTML code loads 3 JavaScript files either provide all 3 files or remove them from HTML code. It's even better to move the JavaScript code into the HTML code for questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jabaa I thought you meant something else. It didn't work.

Comment: This is a working example: I have a [index.html](https://jsfiddle.net/amcj91eL/) and a [apply.html](https://jsfiddle.net/1jgxc8Lw/). The `index.html` sets the reference on page load. The form submit redirects to `apply.html` and it reads the correct value at page load. You can start with this code and modify it step by step until the behavior breaks. Then you know which changes caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example. The `index.html` sets the reference on page load. The form submit redirects to `apply.html` and it reads the correct value at page load.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SwinTech</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="apply.html" method="post">
        <div class="consultantinformation">
            <h2> Job reference number: </h2>
            <br>
            <h4 id="jobreference2"> 6LZ9W </h4>
        </div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        localStorage.setItem("jobreference1", "1FN43");
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

apply.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Job Reference Number: <span id="job1"></span></p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("job1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("jobreference1");
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. Do you know why this only works as inline JS and not in an external file?

Comment: @Wheelchaircoder I've tried it and it works exactly the same with JavaScript code in an external file.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try eliminating certain pieces of code to find the problem. Also, is there a way to make it so that it's only stored in local storage if the form is actually submitted?

Comment: @Wheelchaircoder Yes, you can add an event listener that listens on the form's submit event and only then sets the item into the storage.

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the event listener I added. It doesn't work though. I apologise for my constant questions and I promise this is the last. Thank you.

Comment: @Wheelchaircoder Please don't recycle your question to ask a new question. Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer platform. You ask a specific question and get specific answers. Create a new question for this.